# How render error 404 with custom layout with Phoenix?

Tags: phoenix-framework

By default, when an `Ecto.NoResultsError` occurs, the `404.html` file is rendered without layout.

How I could define which layout must use this view?

Comment: Relevant comment in the [documentation](https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix/1.5.6/custom_error_pages.html): [...] we did not render our 404.html.eex template through our application layout, even though we want our error page to have the look and feel of the rest of our site. This is to avoid circular errors. For example, what happens if our application failed due to an error in the layout? Attempting to render the layout again will just trigger another error. So ideally we want to minimize the amount of dependencies and logic in our error templates, sharing only what is necessary.

Answer (score 2):

Finally I do it:

```
defmodule AppWeb.ErrorView do
  use Web, :view

  def render("404.html", assigns) do
    render(Web.ErrorView, "404_page.html",
      layout: {Web.LayoutView, "empty.html"},
      conn: assigns.conn
    )
  end
end
```